# how to get id of textbox typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

I've dynamic `textbox` list with different `id` and also apply `typeahead` `JavaScript` to add functionality of tag and auto search with `ajax`. But I want to get `id` of `textbox` in which I'm typing, means there are 3 textboxes with `id` **txtid1**, **txtid2** & **txtid3** are there and I'm writing in **txtid2** then I want this `id` everytime when my keyup event is call.

Can anyone suggest me what to do and I also want to know that how to get Id from all tag means 3 tag with value **CAR**, **Truck** & **Plan** with `id` **1**, **2** & **3** so @time of submit I want 1,2,3 with tag manager

```js
$('.typeahead').on('keyup', function () {
  var catid = '';
  var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
  jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
    name: 'tags',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: function (query, process) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var category = id;
      console.log('ud='+$(this).attr('id'));
      return $.get('ajax.php', {query: query, gettag: 'gettag', catid: category}, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        return process(data);
      });
    },
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <input name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="typeahead tm-input form-control tm-input-info" id="setattr2" data-original-title="" title="" type="text">
    <input name="hidden-tags" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I have edited my question with code. I want Id of those textbox which I am currently typing for getting tag.

Comment: I want similar functionality as we can with below code.

Comment: var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var category = id; but right now I cannot get id.

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to have the set up of typeahead and AJAX call in the keyup handler function. typeahead should take care of the keyup events. Please, add your HTML markup to understand what you want.

Comment: I have added html markup please check. I want setattr2 while I am typing.